# Execute function if checkbox is checked - Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

In my app I have the following checkbox

```
<input class="js-rooms" 
       id="checkid" 
       ng-keypress="$event.keyCode == 13 && getItem(0)" 
       ng-click="getItem(0)" 
       type="checkbox"/>
```

When the input is clicked and checked then the function `getItem(0)` is called. 
However, when I click the checkbox again and uncheck it and re-submit then the same function gets fired, obviously.

What I would like to do(in the simplest way possible) is to fire off the function `getItem(1)` when the checkbox is clicked and fire off `getItem(0)` when the checkbox is NOT clicked. I am looking for the simplest solution possible. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ng-model` in your checkbox.

And for checkBox angular has **[`ng-true-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)** && **[`ng-false-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)**

Like this
'

```
<input class="js-rooms" 
       ng-model="checkid" 
       ng-keypress="$event.keyCode == 13 && setRoom(checkid)" 
       ng-click="getItem(checkid)"  
       ng-true-value="1"
       ng-false-value="0" 
       type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: Great, elegant and simple! Thank you!